# How to get last inserted row guid in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

for my SQLite database table I am using guid character varying(100) as primary key. I have found the way to return rowID after an insert operation. But I am not using the _id field, only guid. In this case what will be returned by the insert and how I will get the last inserted guid.

Comment: How do you insert the GUID? Doesn't you code already know it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLiteDatabase's [`insert()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) returns an `integer primary key` even if you defined another type of primary key in your table.  Simply use the result from `insert()` to fetch your `guid`:

```
SELECT guid FROM Foo WHERE rowid = x;
```